# How can we check values in array in laravel or php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table for customer details. In my table I have a field calls.
At present calls look like

**customer_details -> calls**

```
voicemail
voicemail_msg1 
message1
voicemail_msg2
voicemail_msg3
message2 
message3
```

I need to list out calls data. But I don't need `voicemail, voicemail_msg1, voicemail_msg2, voicemail_msg3` I need to list out like `Voice Message, Voice Message 1, Voice Message 2, Voice Message 3`.

So these data `Voice Message, Voice Message 1, Voice Message 2, Voice Message 3` need to show instead of `voicemail, voicemail_msg1, voicemail_msg2, voicemail_msg3`. Is it possible with array checking or any other built in function?

i have attached image[image: Here is the view]

So this purpose I have added some code please check and correct me

**HTML**

```
<td>{{ $labels->checkVoiceMailLabel($call->id, $call->answered_by) }}</td>
```

Controller.php

```
public function checkVoiceMailLabel($id, $answered_by)
    {
        //dd($answered_by);
        $result = '';
        $voicemail = [
            "voicemail"       => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail"),
            "voicemail_msg1"  => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail1"),
            "voicemail_msg2"  => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail2"),
            "voicemail_msg3"  => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail3"),
            "voicemail_msg4"  => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail4"),
            "voicemail_msg5"  => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail5"),
            "voicemail_msg6"  => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail6"),
            "voicemail_msg7"  => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail7"),
            "voicemail_msg8"  => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail8"),
            "voicemail_msg9"  => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail9"),
            "voicemail_msg10" => trans("messages.callListTableVoicemail10")
        ];

        dd($voicemail[$answered_by]);

        if($answered_by == $voicemail[$answered_by]){
            $result = $voicemail[$answered_by];
        }
        else{
            $result            = Call::select('answered_by')
                ->where('id', $id)
                ->where('answered_by', $answered_by)
                ->first();
        }
        /*dd($result);*/
    }
```

So expecting result is:

```
Voice Message
Voice Message 1 
message1
Voice Message 2
Voice Message 3
message2 
message3
```

Comment: Take a look at `array_filter()`.

Comment: @SougataBose This not a filtering problem. Is it possible with array checking or any other built in function to check array data

Comment: filter the array and remove data containing `voicemail`